# unknown hundereds of hits on my cloud server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, apache2, denial-of-service

I have an apache2 server on google cloud platform and for some days almost daily I am observing denial of service kind of absurd page hits on my apache3 server from unknown IPs.

Please see the picture attached .

Can somebody help how to get over this issue.[image]

[image]

Comment: Check how many IPs access your server. From the image above I see only one

Comment: I would switch on firewall rule logging and look at the details of what has passed through the firewall.   If you have port 80 wide open to everyone then what you are seeing is fully anticipated where you would have bad actors trying to probe your web server.

Comment: added another screenshot @RomeoNinov

Comment: Close all the ports except 80,443,22 as @Kolban sugest. And activate (if its available) anti DDoS protection from the platform

Comment: About second image: you have hit or two per day so IMHO this is not a problem for you.

Comment: Install a software firewall that supports HTTP Error 404 detection. After X attempts in 5 minutes that result in 404, block the IP address for an hour (or a day, etc). They will go away and pick on another IP address.

Comment: Another suggestion to block these "Script Kiddies". Generally they do not access your site via hostnames. They just blindly hit IP addresses. In your web server configuration, do not respond to requests that do not have a valid HTTP Host header.

Comment: There are crawlers all over the web looking for unsecured login pages, this is normal. Set up Cloud Armor if you're concerned about this kind of traffic.

Comment: @TravisWebb - Can you suggest a rule for this? This would make for a great self-answered question.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your origin / back-end server using [Cloud Armour](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) and use load balancer with cloud cdn to mitigate this issue.